# __BASE_FILE__ macro resolving full file path, not just the file name

Tags: gcc, compilation, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to get the filename using the `__BASE_FILE__` preprocessor macro, however it is expanding to the full path, similar to the `__FILE__` macro. Why is this?

I'm using gcc version 7.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this?

`__BASE_FILE__` expands to the path that was given to the compiler. Therefore, if you pass a full path to the compiler, then `__BASE_FILE__` will expand to the a full path. If you pass a relative name to the compiler, then `__BASE_FILE__` will expand to the relative name.

For example, if you compile with `g++ ../path/to/file.cpp` then `__BASE_FILE__` will expand to `"../path/to/file.cpp"`.